# Flutter: Open social media apps with account links

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, linkedin-api, url-launcher

I want to redirect users to social media apps (Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn) when they have the apps installed. I've been using the `url_launcher` package with the following implementation.

```
    Future<void> _openFacebook() async {
    try {
      Uri fbBundleUri = Uri.parse(
          'fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/{profile_url}');
      var canLaunchNatively = await canLaunchUrl(fbBundleUri);

      if (canLaunchNatively) {
        await launchUrl(fbBundleUri);
      } else {
        await launchUrl(
            Uri.parse(
                'fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/{profile_url}'),
            mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
      }
    } catch (e, st) {
      //
    }
  }
```

After upgrading the package and the project to Flutter 3, the implementation seems to be broken. On Android devices, it redirects to the Facebook app, but not the user profile page, and on iOS, it opens in web view, which is not the desired solution.

Could you please help me to understand what was changed on platforms, and how can I redirect to social media user profile pages if the corresponding app is already installed? Searched, but couldn't find any relative information.
Thanks in advance.